# 50 instances of PHP killing my web server?

Tags: php, wordpress, memory-leak

I was having an "out of memory" problem earlier. I just left top open and it froze on the screen right as it ran out of memory. i have a single user listed with about 50 instances of "php" listed. how do i limit the number of instances PHP is allowed to open? or the number of instances of PHP that a single user is allowed to use? why is it using so many instances of PHP? it's a wordpress website.

Comment: It's fairly trivial to set up a process / thread limit on php-fpm using its configuration file. I don't have access to my server right now to check it directly, but there will be dozens of tutorials online. What version of PHP are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, the default php-fpm configuration is using more RAM than you have available. You need to configure PHP-FPM so it doesn't run you out of resources, as per a guide like [this one](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/adjusting-php-fpm-performance-low-memory/).

```
sudo nano /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
```

You need to decide on the PM type to use. [Read this](https://haydenjames.io/php-fpm-tuning-using-pm-static-max-performance/). ondemand is usually good for low memory servers that get little traffic. I think I use dynamic for my main PHP pool as it keeps a few PHP processes always available and waiting to service a request, then ondemand for my testing PHP pool that's rarely used. ondemand means more latency as a php process needs to be started, but for lower volume sites that's probably ok.

The configuration could look something like this if you have low memory and low traffic

```
pm = ondemand

; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
; This value sets the limit on the number of simultaneous requests that will be
; served. Equivalent to the ApacheMaxClients directive with mpm_prefork.
; Equivalent to the PHP_FCGI_CHILDREN environment variable in the original PHP
; CGI. The below defaults are based on a server without much resources. Don't
; forget to tweak pm.* to fit your needs.
; Note: Used when pm is set to 'static', 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'
; Note: This value is mandatory.
pm.max_children = 5

; The number of child processes created on startup.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Default Value: min_spare_servers + (max_spare_servers - min_spare_servers) / 2
;pm.start_servers = 2

; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
;pm.min_spare_servers = 1

; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'dynamic'
; Note: Mandatory when pm is set to 'dynamic'
;pm.max_spare_servers = 3

; The number of seconds after which an idle process will be killed.
; Note: Used only when pm is set to 'ondemand'
; Default Value: 10s
pm.process_idle_timeout = 60s;

; The number of requests each child process should execute before respawning.
; This can be useful to work around memory leaks in 3rd party libraries. For
; endless request processing specify '0'. Equivalent to PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS.
; Default Value: 0
pm.max_requests = 50
```

If you get higher traffic you might be better off using dynamic and tuning the values so you have enough servers running within the CPU / RAM you have available.

**PHP 5.6**

On my AWS t2.nano I have two pools. Here's the definitions for my dynamic pool that services production requests

**File: /etc/php-fpm-5.6.d/www.conf**

```
pm = dynamic
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.max_children = 4
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.max_spare_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_requests = 25
```

Here's my test pool, which is for my test server which I access rarely

**File: /etc/php-fpm-5.6.d/testpool.conf**

```
pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 2
pm.process_idle_timeout = 120s;
pm.max_requests = 50
```

Comment: php-fpm APPEARS to be the answer, but im having trouble executing your answer. i dont have a folder named "/etc/php/7.0/..." either way, i accepted because that seems to be what i need to figure out. it at least sent me on the right path, though it wasnt a straight shot to success. thanks for the answer.

Comment: You didn't say what version of PHP you use. Look in /etc/php to find it, or something like "which php" may also help. Anyway, this should set you on your way towards fixing this problem.

Comment: right. itll set me on my way. strange thing is that i dont have an /etc/php directory at all

Comment: On a side note...you have a very low number for `pm.max_requests`. What's going on there? I would not expect PHP to need to be recycled so quickly.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include paths on my own Amazon Linux system. If you can call a [phpinfo page](https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204643880/how-can-i-create-a-phpinfo.php-page) it might point you at the correct config file to modify -

Comment: @MichaelHampton I had some poor quality PHP, and it's a very lightly loaded server. It's worked fine with that configuration for years. Sometimes requests are queued, but not often.